# Problema usando cakephp 2.6 - Undefined index

Tags: cakephp, índices, undefined

Bom dia amigos, estou aprendendo a programar no cake há pouco tempo e estou com algumas dificuldades.

Segue os models e controllers.

```
Recibo.php (Model)

class Recibo extends AppModel{
    public $name = 'Recibo';
    public $belongsTo = array('Loja');  
    public $nomeloja = 'nome';
    public $nomefuncionario = 'nome';
}

Loja.php (model)

class Loja extends AppModel {
        public $name = 'Loja';
        public $hasOne = array('Recibos');      
        public $nomeloja = 'nome';
        public $displayField = 'nome';
}

RecibosController.php

class RecibosController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array ('Html','Form');
public $name = 'Recibos';
public $components = array('Session');
public $uses = array('Recibos', 'Loja','Funcionario');  

        public function index()
        {
            $this->loadModel('Recibos');
            $lojas = $this->Loja->find('all');
            $this->set('loja',$lojas);
            $this->set('recibos', $this->Recibos->find('all'));             
        }
```

Campo onde exibo o recibo e gostaria de exibir o nome da loja na frente.

```
echo $recibo['Recibos']['loja_id'] . '&nbsp-&nbsp' .  $recibo['Loja']['nome'];
```

O que eu estou errando?

Pois, quando clico em "Notice" no erro eu verifico que o nome e id da loja vai na variavel `$loja` e não na variavel `$recibos` (que é a que eu estou listando)

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Valeu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos ver alguns pontos:

- Toda referência ao seu *model* deve ser feita no singular por [convenção do CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions). Alguns locais que você deve corrigir:

No *model* `Loja`:

```
public $hasOne = array('Recibo');
```

Na variável `$uses`:

```
public $uses = array('Recibo', 'Loja', 'Funcionario');
```

E para realizar a consulta:

```
$this->set('recibos', $this->Recibo->find('all'));
```

---

- Todo *controller* já carrega o seu *model* primário, no caso do seu `RecibosController`, o *model* `Recibo` já vem carregado, então não é necessário incluí-lo na variável `$uses` e nem utilizar o método `loadModel()`. [Veja aqui](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses) a referência na documentação.

---

- Não entendi muito bem o que você deseja fazer em sua *view*, precisaria de um contexto maior. Mas se sua intenção é listar os recibos e assim exibir `id` e `nome` da loja, a ideia é justamente essa, já que você tem uma relação 1:1 entre loja e recibo. Se for este o caso, também é a mesma questão do uso em singular.

Assim:

```
foreach ($recibos as $recibo) {
    echo $recibo['Recibo']['loja_id'] . ' - ' .  $recibo['Loja']['nome'];
}
```

Comment: Legal meu xará Paulo. Era isso mesmo. Estou começando a pouco tempo no cakephp, esse é meu segundo projeto. Obrigado pela ajuda.